# Remove the [Environment: Sandbox]

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

I am new on iOS development and am having the following issue.

My app has in-app-purchases, it is working fine but when I click a button, this `UIAlertView` is coming up.

[image: Image of iOS alert box - two buttons (cancel and buy) and has '[Environment: Sandbox]' in text]

I would like to remove the `[Environment: Sandbox]` text. My purchase type is "Non-Consumable", is this possible?

Comment: Is this in your development (i.e. not release) version? It's probably just letting you know that pressing "buy" wont really charge you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sandbox environment is used for testing in-app purchases. When your app and its purchases are live on the App Store, the live environment will be used and that message will not appear in purchase dialogs.

Comment: okey, i got it :),what should be the type?is the "Non-Consumable" correct?

Comment: That depends on what you're selling. "Consumable" purchases are things like in-game currency or powerups, "Non-consumables" are things like feature unlocks and additional content.

Comment: Ok,Thank you for your interest.